# How to summarise unique values in columns of a dataframe by multiple nested blocks in R

Tags: r, datetime, nested, plyr

I have a dataframe with columns for datetime, id, time and depth. I am using ddply to get the mean time and depth for each unique datetime, as there are duplicate datetime rows. However, within each datetime block, there may be more than one unique 'id’ value, and again duplicate rows for individual ids. Therefore, what I need to do for each datetime block is actually calculate the mean of all the unique times taken from within the id blocks. i.e. I first need to get the unique time values from within each id block, then I want to calculate the mean for all of the unique time values returned using this method for each datetime block. I am trying to use %>% to do this, but this is new syntax for me and I am struggling. Any help, or alternative suggestions within the ddply wrapper for datetime would be appreciated. I provide an example below.

```
> dput(df3)
structure(list(datetime = c("23/03/2017 14:13:45", "23/03/2017 14:13:45", 
"23/03/2017 14:13:45", "23/03/2017 14:13:45", "23/03/2017 14:13:45", 
"23/03/2017 14:13:45", "23/03/2017 14:13:45", "23/03/2017 14:13:45", 
"23/03/2017 14:13:45", "23/03/2017 14:13:45", "23/03/2017 14:15:15", 
"23/03/2017 14:15:15", "23/03/2017 14:15:15", "23/03/2017 14:15:15", 
"23/03/2017 14:15:45", "23/03/2017 14:15:45", "23/03/2017 14:16:15", 
"23/03/2017 14:16:15", "23/03/2017 14:16:15", "23/03/2017 14:16:15", 
"23/03/2017 14:16:15", "23/03/2017 14:16:15", "23/03/2017 14:16:15"
), id = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 18L), 
    time = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L), dep = c(0.448675132, 
    0.448675132, 0.448675132, 0.448675132, 0.448675132, 0.448675132, 
    0.448675132, 0.448675132, 0.448675132, 0.448675132, 0.285520539, 
    0.285520539, 0.285520539, 0.285520539, 0.316112025, 0.316112025, 
    0.326309187, 0.356900674, 0.356900674, 0.356900674, 0.38749216, 
    0.326309187, 0.326309187)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-23L))
```

My attempt which doesn’t work:

```
#convert datetime to POSIXct
df3$datetime = as.POSIXct(strptime(df3$datetime, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"), tz="UTC")

#Now condense the dateframe by unique datetime summarising tim and dep cols
  dfCondensed = ddply(df3, .(datetime), summarise,
                      #get the mean time for each unique datetime, but calculate this using 
                      #all the unique time values found within each unique id 
                      meantime = group_by(id) %>% unique(time) %>% mean(),
                      #do the same as above but for dep
                      meandep = group_by(id) %>% unique(dep) %>% mean())
```

## Desired output

```
> dfCondensed
             datetime   tim       dep
1 23/03/2017 14:13:45 10.00 0.4486751
2 23/03/2017 14:15:15  2.00 0.2855205
3 23/03/2017 14:15:45  2.00 0.3161120
4 23/03/2017 14:16:15  1.75 0.3492528
```

Answer (score 2):

here is a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df3)
unique(df3, by = c("datetime", "id"))[, .(mean.time = mean(time),
                                          mean.dep = mean(dep)), 
                                      by = .(datetime)][]

              datetime mean.time  mean.dep
1: 23/03/2017 14:13:45     10.00 0.4486751
2: 23/03/2017 14:15:15      2.00 0.2855205
3: 23/03/2017 14:15:45      2.00 0.3161120
4: 23/03/2017 14:16:15      1.75 0.3492528
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for :

```
library(dplyr)

df3 %>%
   distinct() %>%
   group_by(datetime) %>%
   summarise(dep = mean(dep), mean = mean(time))

#  datetime              dep  mean
#  <chr>               <dbl> <dbl>
#1 23/03/2017 14:13:45 0.449 10   
#2 23/03/2017 14:15:15 0.286  2   
#3 23/03/2017 14:15:45 0.316  2   
#4 23/03/2017 14:16:15 0.349  1.75
```

Comment: thanks, this does give me an output but what I need is code to achieve what I want to do within the ddply wrapper as above as I am already summarising a bunch of other columns as well in different ways within this function. I just need a line of code (or two - one for meantime and one for meandep) that returns the means WITHIN the ddply wrapper that is already being applied to the datetime blocks. Therefore, I cannot use group_id again on datetime.

Comment: @jjulip `plyr` is [retired](https://github.com/hadley/plyr). Do you mind switching to `dplyr` ? You can do all the summarisation and other tasks with it.

Comment: Yes I have updated. Thanks. But I still don't understand how to get this working as I require. The problem I have (which I cannot give an example of here) is that I have a large dataframe with lots of other columns, in addition to time and depth, so I think your code is doing something else when I type distinct() other than making it specific to my 'id' grouping, which is what I need. Please could you tell me how to solve this?

Comment: @jjulip I see , in that case can you try `df3 %>%
  distinct(datetime, id) %>%
  group_by(datetime) %>%
  summarise(dep = mean(dep), mean = mean(time))`  which will give you unique rows only for `datetime` and `id`.

Comment: When I try this it cannot find my objects (ie dep) from within the df3. I just get an error message telling me that "object 'dep' not found".

Comment: For each datetime block, I need to find all the unique 'dep' or 'time' values from each unique id (i.e. as the dep and times are duplicated I just want each value once from within each id block). Then for a datetime block, I want to use all of these unique values from the id blocks COMBINED to calculate the mean. Does that make sense?

Comment: For example, if you look at my data above, time 14:16:15 has 4 unique IDs and for each of those I just want the unique 'time' values once to be used to calculate the mean, so there will be 4 values used in the calculation in this case!

Comment: @jjulip the error message suggests that your column name is not `dep` as shown in the example but something else in your data. Please use the same column name as you have in your data instead of `dep`.

Comment: no I am using the above data and example exactly as it is with the code you have given and it gives that error. It doesn't matter what dataset I use, it doesn't work. Once you add object names in the distinct() function it spits out the error. Does it work for you with my example data?

Comment: yes, it gives me the exact same output as shown in my answer if I use the sample data from your post.

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense. I am literally running this as above letter by letter using my example data and it won't find the column objects. I've also tried it with a different dataset and the same thing happens in each instance. I do not have any non-base packages loaded other that dplyr so it can't be related to this. Any ideas? I would really like to get your solution working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200555/discussion-between-ronak-shah-and-jjulip).

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R`

```
df4 <- unique(df3)
by(df4[c('time', 'dep')], df4[c('datetime')], FUN = colMeans)
```

---

Or with `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(cbind(time, dep) ~ datetime, df4, mean)
#     datetime  time       dep
#1 23/03/2017 14:13:45 10.00 0.4486751
#2 23/03/2017 14:15:15  2.00 0.2855205
#3 23/03/2017 14:15:45  2.00 0.3161120
#4 23/03/2017 14:16:15  1.75 0.3492528
```

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't help me because I have a large number of columns in my dataframe, and I want to summarise data from multiple columns at the same time, not simple just calculate the means for two columns, which was why I was using the ddply function for the datetime blocks. I also need to take unique values from each id block.